# How do you tell which category the property belongs to？

Tags: swift, type-alias

```
typealias Names = String
typealias Works = String

let a: Names = Names()
let b: Works = Works()

if a is Names {// a is not Works
}
```

How do I know if "a" belongs to "Names" instead of "Works"?

Thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to do here? Seems like you need a struct not typealias

Comment: I want to inherit String, but I can't. Can you help me?

Comment: You cannot inherit String. It is not a class. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Is there a way to inherit String? I need to know externally what kind of String it is, not just that it's a String.

Comment: Not inherit but you can wrap it in a struct or use an enum with an associated value but it's hard to say what is best since we don't know your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I know if "a" belongs to "Names" instead of "Works"?

You don’t, because it doesn’t. They are all names for the same thing. They are completely interchangeable. There is no sense in which something is a Names but not a Works.

Comment: Is there a way to inherit String? I need to know externally what kind of String it is, not just that it's a String.

Comment: There is no such thing as a “kind of string”. I ask you one more time, what are you really trying to do? Why do you think you need kinds of string?

Comment: @醉翁之意 If there are a set of predefined names then yo should be using enums.